# Azure DevOps Pipeline - Control trigger between pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I have a question about the trigger issue of multiple pipelines.

To be specific: for example I have pipeline A and pipeline B

- Pipeline A: has a cron scheduler on midnight
- Pipeline B: is triggered by A when A is completed

This workflow is okay when we want them to run in sequence but in daytime, we may need to execute pipeline A manually so an unexpected execution of pipeline B is triggered.

I am wondering if there is any solution to identify how pipeline A is triggered. Like if A is triggered by the scheduler then continue B, but if A is started manually, then do not continue B.

Current solution:
So currently I have set up multiple pipelines for autorun and manual run separately, but it may become messy.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation section on predefined pipeline variables?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to configure this via pipeline resource definition

```
pipelines:
- pipeline: string # Required as first property. ID of the pipeline resource.
  project: string # Project for the source; defaults to current project.
  source: string # Name of the pipeline that produces the artifact.
  version: string # The pipeline run number to pick the artifact, defaults to latest pipeline successful across all stages; used only for manual or scheduled triggers.
  branch: string # Branch to pick the artifact. Optional; defaults to all branches, used only for manual or scheduled triggers.
  tags: [ string ] # List of tags required on the pipeline to pickup default artifacts. Optional; used only for manual or scheduled triggers.
  trigger:  # Specify none to disable, true to include all branches, or use the full syntax as described in the following examples.
    enabled: boolean # Whether the trigger is enabled; defaults to true.
    branches: branches # Branches to include or exclude for triggering a run.
    stages: [ string ] # List of stages that when matched will trigger the pipeline.
    tags: [ string ] # List of tags that when matched will trigger the pipeline.
```

And it is also not available in [the pipeline resource metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-pipelines-pipeline?view=azure-pipelines#pipeline-resource-metadata-as-predefined-variables)

```
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.projectName
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.projectID
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.pipelineName
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.pipelineID
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runName
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runID
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runURI
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceBranch
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceCommit
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceProvider
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.requestedFor
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.requestedForID
```

And it looks that your option can be to take:

- run id `resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runID`
- call [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0#buildreason)

An another approach could be to check reason in pipeline A and [trigger pipeline b via REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) only when reason is `scheduled` (`Build.Reason` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Comment: @ECH could you mark my reply as answer if it helped you?